# Qt5 Video Player QtMultimedia QGraphicsVideoItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Hey stackies currently trying to create some basic code that just plays a video file from local source (as trying to get that working then try and implement rtsp). below is my current code. If anyone can give me an idea where im going wrong that would be great.

Currently the code is failing with the error

C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\msvc2010_opengl\examples\multimediawidgets\videographicsitem\main.cpp:58: error: C2664: 'QGraphicsScene::addItem' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QGraphicsVideoItem *' to 'QGraphicsItem *'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

I presume I have to typecast the variable being inserted to additem. However have no idea how to do this with two Qclasses. If someone has an example of a basic player that just contains a video frame and plays the second you start the program ( not even a play button preferably). If anyone has anything like that please let me know as would make my life alot easier.
Main.cpp

```
#include "videoplayer.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
//VideoPlayer player;
//QGraphicsView graphicsView;
QMediaPlayer *player ;

QGraphicsVideoItem *item;
QGraphicsView *graphicsView;
QGraphicsScene *scene;
player->setVideoOutput(item);
// scene->addItem(item);
graphicsView->scene()->addItem(item);
graphicsView->show();

player->setMedia(QUrl("rtsp://192.168.100.58:8554/stream"));
player->play();

graphicsView->show();

return app.exec();
}
```

Videoplayer.cpp

```
#include "videoplayer.h"

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QVideoSurfaceFormat>
#include <QGraphicsVideoItem>

VideoPlayer::VideoPlayer(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
, mediaPlayer(0, QMediaPlayer::VideoSurface)
, videoItem(0)
, playButton(0)
, positionSlider(0)
{
videoItem = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
videoItem->setSize(QSizeF(640, 480));

QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
QGraphicsView *graphicsView = new QGraphicsView(scene);

scene->addItem(videoItem);

QSlider *rotateSlider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
rotateSlider->setRange(-180,  180);
rotateSlider->setValue(0);

connect(rotateSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
        this, SLOT(rotateVideo(int)));

QAbstractButton *openButton = new QPushButton(tr("Open..."));
connect(openButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(openFile()));

playButton = new QPushButton;
playButton->setEnabled(false);
playButton->setIcon(style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MediaPlay));

connect(playButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
        this, SLOT(play()));

positionSlider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
positionSlider->setRange(0, 0);

connect(positionSlider, SIGNAL(sliderMoved(int)),
        this, SLOT(setPosition(int)));

QBoxLayout *controlLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
controlLayout->setMargin(0);
controlLayout->addWidget(openButton);
controlLayout->addWidget(playButton);
controlLayout->addWidget(positionSlider);

QBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(graphicsView);
layout->addWidget(rotateSlider);
layout->addLayout(controlLayout);

setLayout(layout);

mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoItem);
connect(&mediaPlayer, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QMediaPlayer::State)),
        this, SLOT(mediaStateChanged(QMediaPlayer::State)));
connect(&mediaPlayer, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), this, SLOT(positionChanged(qint64)));
connect(&mediaPlayer, SIGNAL(durationChanged(qint64)), this, SLOT(durationChanged(qint64)));
}

VideoPlayer::~VideoPlayer()
{
}


void VideoPlayer::openFile()
{
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Movie"),QDir::homePath());
//QString fileName = "rtsp://192.168.100.58:8554/stream";
if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
    mediaPlayer.setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileName));

    playButton->setEnabled(true);
}
}

void VideoPlayer::play()
{
switch(mediaPlayer.state()) {
case QMediaPlayer::PlayingState:
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    break;
default:
    mediaPlayer.play();
    break;
}
}
```

Videoplayer.h

```
#ifndef VIDEOPLAYER_H
#define VIDEOPLAYER_H

#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QMovie>
#include <QWidget>

class QAbstractButton;
class QSlider;
class QGraphicsVideoItem;

class VideoPlayer : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
VideoPlayer(QWidget *parent = 0);
~VideoPlayer();

QSize sizeHint() const { return QSize(800, 600); }

public slots:
void openFile();
void play();

private slots:
void mediaStateChanged(QMediaPlayer::State state);
void positionChanged(qint64 position);
void durationChanged(qint64 duration);
void setPosition(int position);
void rotateVideo(int angle);

private:
QMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
QGraphicsVideoItem *videoItem;
QAbstractButton *playButton;
QSlider *positionSlider;
};

#endif
```

.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = videographicsitem

QT += multimedia multimediawidgets

HEADERS   += videoplayer.h

SOURCES   += main.cpp \
         videoplayer.cpp

target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/multimediawidgets/videographicsitem
INSTALLS += target

QT+=widgets
```

ALSO just tried this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
QMediaPlayer media;
const QString file = "C:/Users/nick.herniman/Downloads/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov";
QUrl url(QFileInfo(file).absoluteFilePath());
media.setMedia(url);
media.play();
return a.exec();
}
```

which works but only plays the audio of the file anyone know what im doing wrong here (does it need to be in a gui window or is it ok for me to just do it in a console application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing weird. :-)

It helps, when the compiler knows, that a `QGraphicsVideoItem` is a `QGraphicsItem`. And for the compiler to know this, `#include <QGraphicsVideoItem>` should be present.

I see, you have it in Videoplayer.cpp. But main.cpp sees only that there is a class `QGraphicsVideoItem` declared. You did a fine forward declaration. But what this class is... no way to know for the compiler in main.cpp. Add `#include <QGraphicsVideoItem>` to your main.cpp.

Comment: Ah missed off QGraphicsVideoItem how silly :P.  To give you an idea just want a basic video player that either plays by a play/pause button or just plays straight away. Only other example I found that works only output audio so not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: To let you know once I have done that I get a ton of errors. related to unresolved external symbol, or i want to use from the .cpp file is the play/pause function all the rest i don't care about, tried commenting the rest out and sadly it compiles but program finishes unexpectedly (remove any reference to the unresolved external symbol functions, which i don't use).

Comment: But if u can look at the code i just uploaded for a more basic player and tell me why i get no video that would be great.

Comment: I answered your question. Don't slide new questions in comments in. If you have other problems, ask another question.

Comment: @Greenflow, just out of curiosity, since I don't have Qt version by hand - the `QGraphicsVideoItem` doc page does not say it inherits from `QGraphicsItem`, nor does the `QGraphicsItem` page say that `QGraphicsVideoItem` inherits from it, but still they are actually related?

Comment: QGraphicsVideoItem inherits QGraphicsObject, which inherits QGraphicsItem.

Comment: " If someone has an example of a basic player that just contains a video frame and plays the second you start the program ( not even a play button preferably). If anyone has anything like that please let me know as would make my life alot easier." So i should ask this question again in another thread even though it was my reason for posting ? (mind you did find my own example but as stated doesn't play video only audio, something wrong with QMediaPlayer in windows7 ?).

Comment: @Greenflow, thanks, docs didn't state that, so far with QT I've always  tended to rely on their docs 100%, now I'll now the documentation is not totally full.

Comment: @Rudolfs Bundulis ha it's the reason why i'm struggling so much Documentation seems a bit of a mess really at the moment.

Comment: @ION, Usually how it works here: One clearly defined question, if possible at least one clear answer. If your question is too broad, or too unclear there is always a risk, that it gets closed. You gave us an error message, you got an explanation of this error. Now you can go on and try again. If you have more trouble... ask. Your general 'does anyone has an example...' is also a dangerous question here. It **might** be interpreted as 'shopping list'. Frowned upon and easily closed. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Comment: Well hell created a new post now anyway. But don't see how asking for a basic example of QVideoPlayer when there isn't a single decent working example of it anywhere on the net would be unacceptable. But hey I find quite a few of SO rules a bit nuts. Personnally i feel if it's related to the question whats the point in creating a new one (but hey ill follow the rules no matter how stupid i think they are).

Comment: @Greenflow after reading that post quite frankly the rules seem crazy. Instead of having one post from me for example related to all my problems related to QVideoPlayer we have to write one for each question (making finding a solution to a problem alot more work with little to no benefits of it). Then on top of that this site essentially believes in reinventing the wheel for every person (shopping list post are actually the most useful because they provide you with a base to learn from and saves the same thing being created hundreds of times), just me having a moan at the stupid rules

Comment: Not my rules. Not even sure I interpret them correctly. But better safe than sorry. And keep in mind: The answers are not only for you. SO is a repository of questions and answers. Makes it easier for other to search, when there isn't a huge follow up in the comments. Is this 'give me an example' really a shopping list? Depends on what a moderator thinks, or a five high level players here. Always a bit unpredictable.

Comment: Yea just felt like moaning at you cause got noone else to :D. Actually is was more awkward finding the answer with a new thread for each question cause meant there was 10 times the amount of posts with all asking tiny questions, why i ended up posting couldn't find what i was looking for (I would of been happy to trawl through a single post if it was just related to QVideoPlayer etc). Yea can understand they don't want to do code for people but how are people supposed to learn new techniques if you can't find any examples? But hey would love to see why they do this way and try and defend it.

Comment: This is more a discussion for a chat room. There are many gray areas. And in meta you can see that things like that are also again and again controversially discussed. Even if your questions was ok, see it this way: From my experience smaller, well defined questions have a much higher probability to get good answers.

Comment: Yea true is more helpful for the posting shame the same can't be said for the author. But anyway thanks for ur help so far @Greenflow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simplest Example in Qt5:

```
QMediaPlayer *mediaPlayer = new QMediaPlayer(this, QMediaPlayer::VideoSurface);
QGraphicsVideoItem *videoItem = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
videoItem->setPos(100,100);
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->GV_VideoPlayer->setScene(scene);
scene->addItem(videoItem);
QString fileName = "/root/sampleVideos/videoplayback.mp4";
if(!fileName.isEmpty())
{
    mediaPlayer->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileName));
}
mediaPlayer->play();
mediaPlayer->setVideoOutput(videoItem);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. It really helps me a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

It is actually really weird that the QT documentation states a very similar example ( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qgraphicsvideoitem.html ), while the objects are actually not related. Apart from that, just looking through the QT documentation since I haven't worked with QT for a while - does creating a dummy `QGraphicsItem`, setting it as a parent to your `QGraphicsVideoItem` and then adding that dummy item to the scene help? I guess it would go something like this

```
QGraphicsItem* dummy = new QGraphicsItem;
item = new QGraphicsVideoItem(dummy);
graphicsView->scene()->addItem(dummy);
```

Comment: Ha it might do but by that point i really won't have a clue what i am doing :D. Just looking for the most basic example of playing a video, and as you can see at the bottom of my post been able to create a console application that plays the video's sound but not it's video, any suggestions ?